# Problemas en POO con java en kali linux

Tags: java, poo

tengo problemas al intentar compilar un programa en con el paradigma de POO.
Ambos archivos estan en la misma carpeta. Pero me bota el mismo error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow, te recomiendo que cambies la imagen con código para que pueda copiarse y replicar el error. Pasate en la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Prueba eliminando la lineá 4. Y el nombre de tu clase y de tu archivo debe tener el mismo nombre, cambia el nombre de `class myClass` por `class Primer` y vuelve a probar

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya compila el codigo ahora si